# js mulipe-input does not pass all values?

Tags: javascript, php, html, node.js, arrays

i have problem plz help
when i click on button it pass just an array(speaker) without any other parameters(sub,compose)
i try to sent just the parameter (sub,compose) but its does not pass,
i need when i click button pass all(array(speaker) and (sub,compose)
this is hrml code

```
<multi-input>
        <input list="speakers">
      <datalist id="speakers">
        <option value="Banquo"></option>
        <option value="Bishop Stokesly of London"></option>
        <option value="Caesar’s Second Watchman"></option>
        <option value="Celia"></option>
        <option value="Cleopatra"></option>
        <option value="Dogberry"></option>
        <option value="Falstaff"></option>
        <option value="First Servant"></option>
        <option value="Hamlet"></option>
        <option value="Juliet"></option>
        <option value="Macbeth"></option>
      </datalist>
    </multi-input>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Subject:" id="sub">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea id="compose" class="form-control" style="height: 300px">
     <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="get"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i> Send</button>
```

and this is js code

```
const getButton = document.getElementById('get');
var sub = document.getElementById('sub').value;
var compose= document.getElementById('compose').value;
const multiInput = document.querySelector('multi-input'); 
getButton.onclick = () => {
var src="sent.php?sub="+multiInput.getValues()+'&sub='+sub+'&compose='+compose+'';
window.location.href=src;
}
```

just the array (multi-input) pass the other not whay ?

Answer (score 0):

To specify your array as URL parameters, you need to add "[]" before "=" sign. In that way php recognizes it as array. Otherwise the value will be just a string.

```
/*------ Change This -------*/
var src="sent.php?sub="+multiInput.getValues()+'&sub='+sub+'&compose='+compose+'';
window.location.href=src;

/*----- To this -------*/
var src="sent.php?sub[]="+multiInput.getValues()+'&sub='+sub+'&compose='+compose+'';
window.location.href=src;
```

Secondly, since your 'onclick' function does not update the values of variables you've defined above; it just not get the latest value of them. To solve this issue moving variables inside the function is enough.

```
const getButton = document.getElementById('get');
const multiInput = document.querySelector('multi-input'); 
getButton.onclick = () => {

/*----- Define them in here -------*/
var sub = document.getElementById('sub').value;
var compose= document.getElementById('compose').value;

var src="sent.php?sub="+multiInput.getValues()+'&sub='+sub+'&compose='+compose+'';
window.location.href=src;
}
```

Comment: when i sent speakers=Banquo and sub=any and compose=any i get:

/sent.php?sub[]=Banquo&sub=&compose=[object%20HTMLInputElement]

Comment: For the compose element, since it is textarea you need to close it in your html code with </textarea>

Comment: i close in realy code
but the result is the same

Comment: Ok, I checked the code again and there are multiple problems exist. Since I see the textarea not closed, I need to say it again as first problem. Make sure to close before defining the button itself.
Secondly, The onclick function is getting parameters from outside the function, it does not update the values of sub and compose. It just gets the first value from page load stage. Move your variables inside the 'onclick' function then it will work. I will update the answer now.

Comment: its work thnak you so much brother >> thats very good

Comment: Good to hear. :)  You can select the answer as correct to prevent other developers lose their times reading this. Hope you have a great day brother.

Comment: who can i do that ?